# What will be the correct preposition for the blank?

Tags: prepositions

The soldiers held the fort ***_*__** all attacks. What will the most suitable word be?

Comment: I would guess "against" but for future reference it helps to give some context to your questions: say what you want the meaning of the sentence to be. That way if there are several alternatives that are all grammatically correct then people can choose the one that has the meaning that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to ELL Surabhi.

Kindly give us some more details such as where did you read this, what word **you** think in the blank and so on. Always try to give the context as it'll help us to answer the questions.

However, I feel this is the word that may go there.

> The soldiers held the fort **against** all attacks.